# MS Media Foundation Session default presenter - video aspect ratio is wrong

Tags: windows, video, video-capture, ms-media-foundation, uvc

Learning (painfully) how to use the Topology and Session to present a captured video. Nothing fancy - just select a web cam, list its modes, choose a video format and hit "go". In general these are the steps I'm taking to present the video capture:

1. List the available devices with `MFEnumDeviceSources()` filtered by `MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID` and let user select one
2. List the streams based on `GetStreamDescriptorCount()` after activating the source and creating Presentation Descriptors with `CreatePresentationDescriptor()` and let the user select a stream (if multiple streams are available)
3. Display all the supported video formats based on the list of `IMFMediaType`s available through `GetMediaTypeByIndex()` and let the user choose one

Once the exact format is selected I build the Topology this way:

4. call `MFCreateTopology()` to create a new `IMFTopology` object
5. create media sink activation with `MFCreateVideoRendererActivate()`

   1. making sure to call `SetCurrentMediaType()` on the `IMFMediaTypeHandler` object of the currently selected `IMFStreamDescriptor`
6. create the source node with `MFCreateTopologyNode()`, setting its presentation and stream descriptors with the call to `SetUnknown()` and adding that node to the Topology

   1. made sure to set its current `IMFMediaType` to the one chosen by user with `SetCurrentMediaType()`
7. create an output node and call `SetObject()` of it providing the previously created media sink activation object (from step 5 above)
8. connect the source to output with `ConnectOutput()` providing it with the node ID `0`

When the "preview" button is clicked a session `IMFMediaSession` object (created at the app's startup) is set with the new Topology

```
m_session->SetTopology(MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_IMMEDIATE, pTopo);
```

And this is where I see something strange. I set the size of the preview video based on the frame dimensions provided by the `IMFMediaType` that the user chose and the source seems to be producing the video in that format. *However* the renderer is handling the **pixel aspect ratio** incorrectly and is letterboxing/pillarboxing the video while presenting the picture as being stretched either vertically of horizontally.

For the life of me I am unable to find the way to tell the renderer to adjust for the proper pixel aspect ratio (which was set to the proper value in step 5.1 above)

---

The MS's SDK example only shows how to present captured video for uncompressed formats - it doesn't use the `IMFMediaSession` object and works fine for the `YUV2` format but not for the `MJPG`. In fact it worked so well that I thought moving onto using the session would be easy :)

Using the `IMFMediaSession` seems to be the least cumbersome way of supporting compressed video formats, especially the `H.264` that's in the newer `UVC 1.5` standard and any new (`H.265`?) formats that are coming up in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research has shown that one can access the renderer object by querying the session to get the service and then use that service to get the *video display control*. That `IMFVideoDisplayControl` is the object that lets you control various aspects of the rendered video, including the aspect ratio of the image.

Here's how to get to that `IMFVideoDisplayControl` object:

1. get the `IMFGetService`:

   `hr = m_session->QueryInterface<IMFGetService>(&service);`
2. get the `IMFVideoDisplayControl`:

   `hr = service->GetService(MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, IID_IMFVideoDisplayControl, (void**)&control);`

Once you have the display control object you can achieve the rest. In my case (since I knew the actual true geometry of the expected video) the solution was to set the **aspect ratio mode** to `MFVideoARMode_None`